Waterproofing bldc motor with oil
I want to build cheap ROV so I want to waterproof the motors by my self
I was trying to waterproof by casting with epoxy resin but the motor got of balance and started wobbling
So I was wondering if there is a good way for RC ROV to submerge the motor in oil to separate from the sea water?
Or other good, cheap and easy solutions ?

In my experience, good, cheap and easy are often mutually exclusive when making ROV motors.  It may be easier to answer your question if you provide us with some more information.  How big is your ROV going to be? Something about the size of SeaPerch?  Bigger? Smaller?
How deep do you want your ROV to dive?  What kind of currents do you anticipate? (that will determine the minimum "forward speed" your ROV needs).
What is your budget? The S168 Brushless Motors from ROVMaker come sealed with epoxy, and are pretty inexpensive.
